# Inaccurate output of Dynamic Named Range

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I am using the exact same code to name a dynamic range in two workbooks. I use Workbook TestBook1 for testing the code before implementing it to the body of the general code in Workbook 111.

The code is:

```
    Dim HDaER As Worksheet
    Dim HDaERReturnLR As Long
    Dim HDaERReturnLC As Long
    Dim HDaERReturnsDNR As Range
    Dim HDaERReturns As String

    Set HDaER = Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")

        With HDaER.Cells(108, 2).CurrentRegion
            HDaERReturnLR = .Find(What:="*", After:=HDaER.Cells(107, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

            HDaERReturnLC = .Find(What:="*", After:=HDaER.Cells(107, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Set HDaERReturnsDNR = HDaER.Range(HDaER.Cells(108, 2), _
            HDaER.Cells(HDaERReturnLR, HDaERReturnLC))
        End With

        HDaER.Names.Add Name:="HDaERReturns", RefersTo:=HDaERReturnsDNR

        Range("HDaERReturns").Select
```

**The output that I get in TestBook1 is ACCURATE:**
[image: OUTPUT WORKBOOK TESTBOOK1]

**And the output that I get in Workbook 111 is INACCURATE:**
[image: OUTPUT WORKBOOK 111]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you missing a parent workbook reference? If they have the same worksheet names, there could be confusion.

Comment: Hello again @Jeeped: these two workbooks have no relation to each other. There is no parent workbook. I am simply trying to name the range in Worksheet 'HDaER'.

Comment: Workbook TestBook1.xlsm is simply for testing a chunk of code, before I implement it to the general code in Workbook 111.xlsm. There is no relation and no references to any other Workbooks or Worksheets.

Comment: Are you certain that B108 is empty in the second workbook? What does `msgbox HDaER.Cells(108, 2).CurrentRegion.address` show?

Comment: @Jeeped: If that is of any significance, the Worksheet 'HDaER' has another Dynamic Named Range in it.

Comment: @Rory: It says "$A$105:$E$206".

Comment: Can you let us know what you are trying to achieve here? You may not need VBA at all. Are you trying to create a named range that expands with the column and row headings?

Comment: @ojf: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: There are lots of examples of using offset, index, match, count and counta to create dynamically expanding named ranges without VBA. These expand and contract automatically on calculation https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-offset

Comment: @ojf: Thank you! Very helpful, but that is not the point of it all. I need to name the range before calculations are made in it, so I can refer to it for the calculation process and on after. Otherwise, very helpful link!

Comment: @Jeeped: I got it! I found what was wrong with it. Please refer to the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

your whole code could collapse to the following

```
With Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns").Cells(107, 1)
    With .Parent.Range(.End(xlDown), .End(xlToRight))
        .Parent.Names.Add name:="HDaERReturns", RefersTo:=.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)
    End With

    .Range("HDaERReturns").Select
End With
```

Comment: Great Suggestion! I am a fan of minimal code. Will give it a go and will let you know what the output is.

Comment: I get an output with the accurate column and row count, but from cells B214 to E222...

Comment: Why do you think that is?

Comment: I coded that on the basis of data showed in your question. you may give more details about all possible data _face_ to deal with

Comment: No. That is all.

Comment: so try the following: after `Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns").Cells(107, 1)` place `MsgBox .End(xlDown).Address` and then place `MsgBox .End(xlToRight).Address` and see the outcome

Comment: @ DisplayName: I got how to tackle this one. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: Please refer to the edit of my answer below. As I said, very good suggestion, but it doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: did you place `MsgBox .End(xlDown).Address` and `MsgBox .End(xlToRight).Address` after `after Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns").Cells(107, 1)`?

Comment: Please refer to the snippet of the exact code in the answer below.

Comment: If you think that it makes that much of a difference... I tried it out exactly the way that you posted it and still gives me the same output... Sorry, but as I said, it does not work for me for some reason. I don't know why, but it doesn't. I am sorry if that is a disappointment for you, but that is how it is. Also, I like the idea of the code that you have posted as an answer to my  question. However, again, it does not work for me for some reason

Comment: Do you need me to share my screen, or make a GIF, or something?

Comment: However, I will try this approach for defining 'Child' Named Ranges and I will let you know what the result is. If it does, I will accept your answer as THE answer, if that will please you. But that is not going to happen before tomorrow.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb with `...Cells(107, 1)` reference and going `.End(xlDown)` means reaching the last not empty cell before the first empty one along the column. With data setup as you shown, the expression `Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns").Cells(107, 1).End(xlDown).Address` cannot return "$A$117" (the same with 108). And `Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns").Cells(107, 1).End(xlToRight).Address` would return "$E$107" (and not "$E$108", as it seems you're saying) , while `Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns").Cells(108, 1).End(xlToRight).Address` would never return "$E$108"

Comment: So please be accurate about the actual data setup you are dealing with and get proper answer. BTW you'd accept any answer solving your _original_ question and not to please anybody. That means that 1) you must test answers against data you _actually_ gave in the question and accept the one (if any) solving it. 2) you don't have to please anybody

Answer (score 0):

The specification `After:=HDaER.Cells(...)` appears as starting point... In this case I used `After:=HDaER.Cells(107, 1)`, but I have the header **"Volatility"** in `HDaER.Cells(105, 1)`, which means that specifying the start cell for the range with the line `With HDaER.Cells(108, 2).CurrentRegion`and including another specification for direction `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` leads to marking `HDaER.Range(HDaER.Cells(108, 2), HDaER.Cells(105, 1))` as the dynamic range to be named.

The code with the accurate output is:

```
Dim HDaER As Worksheet
Dim HDaERReturnLR As Long
Dim HDaERReturnLC As Long
Dim HDaERReturnsDNR As Range
Dim HDaERReturns As String

Set HDaER = Sheets("HistoricalDataandExcessReturns")

With HDaER.Cells(108, 2).CurrentRegion
            HDaERReturnLR = .Find(What:="*", After:=HDaER.Cells(105, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

            HDaERReturnLC = .Find(What:="*", After:=HDaER.Cells(105, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Set HDaERReturnsDNR = HDaER.Range(HDaER.Cells(108, 2), _
            HDaER.Cells(HDaERReturnLR, HDaERReturnLC))
        End With

        HDaER.Names.Add Name:="HDaERReturns", RefersTo:=HDaERReturnsDNR

        Range("HDaERReturns").Select
```

**Referring to `HDaER.Cell(105, 1)` as the starting point with the specification `After:=HDaER.Cells(105, 1)`, leads to the accurate `.Range` selection.**

[image]

**To answer @DisplayName's comment and Answer:**

Good idea, bad output...

`MsgBox` Last Row displays this result:

[image: MsgBox LR]

`MsgBox` Last Column displays this result:

[image: MsgBox LC]

Output of code (as I previously answered):

[image: OUTPUT]

Exact code input:

[image: Input code]