# Defining Dynamic Named Ranges with their headers as .Name within an already defined Dynamic Named Range

Tags: vba, excel, parent-child, named-ranges

I have the Dynamic Named Range 'HDaERReturns' that starts from `.Cells(108,2)` to last Cell in the range, and I would like to cut it up in columns and name each column with the header that it holds in Row 106.

Example of the current way the Range looks:

```
|    Item    |   EURUSD   |   GBPUSD   |   USDCHF   |   XAUUSD   |
|:----------:|:----------:|:----------:|:----------:|:----------:|
|    Date    | Volatility | Volatility | Volatility | Volatility |
| 06.03.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 05.03.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 04.03.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 02.03.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 01.03.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 28.02.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 27.02.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 26.02.2018 |            |            |            |            |
| 25.02.2018 |            |            |            |            |
```

I need to name each column in Dynamic Named Range 'HDaERReturns', because:

1. I need to loop trough each Cell in each column in Dynamic Named Range 'HDaERReturns' and perform a Normal Log return calculation in it, that refers to another Dynamic Named Range called 'HDaERClose' that I have to cut up in columns and name with the headers. 
   This way I can refer to the calculation stage by coding something like:

   `For Each Column In Range("HDaERReturns")
       ' Set header as .Name
   Next`

   `For Each Cell In Columns
       ' Perform calculations
   Next`

And get an output of such:

[image: OUTPUT]

2. In a later stage of the code I need to Run a Multiple Regression Analysis and exclude each array that holds a P-Value > 0.15 (see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777757/vba-solution-for-automating-multiple-linear-regression-array-filtering-with-p-va) question). In order to exclude the arrays with unsatisfiable correlation value (P-Value) I need the column headers to be the column DNR's names.

I haven't got to the MLR stage, so I haven't corrected the question properly, but that is a different topic. For now I need to create the column dynamic named ranges with their headers as names.

The headers are ever-changing, so are the values in the columns that they correspond with, so it has to be a dynamic approach.

Haven't really got to a meaningful code so far, but I was wondering if anybody can give me some pointers on how to tackle this.

Comment: **Why** do you need to name the columns with a heading that's already there?  What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I betcha this would fall into the category of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/370758).  (The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.)  Take a couple steps back and explain what you would like to accomplish overall.

Comment: @ashleedawg: Thanks for the link, but that is not the case. I really need to name the columns in the range with their headers (problem `x`)- see the edit of the Question.

Comment: @ashleedawg: Any pointers?

Comment: @GMalc: I think you got it wrong. I am trying to assign names to multiple ranges, by using their headers as range names.

Comment: Each column is a Range and each column header is the Range Name...

Comment: @GMalc: "SO is not a code writing service." Read the question carefully.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb, I feel like this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207839/inaccurate-output-of-dynamic-named-range), so you may want to answer my last question there

Comment: @GMalc: It seems that you got a bit salty about being on a different page. I am sorry for  not answering your comments earlier, but I have to sleep some time. I do appreciate what you are saying and I will give you feedback on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for your named range creation.

Note:

1. I am using your dates column to set the height of each dynamic range in case of missing data in columns (assuming date column is most complete).
2. I am assuming your dates column are actually text so using `COUNTA`. Otherwise replace the use of `COUNTA` with `COUNT`.

**Version 1 This creates dynamic named ranges but may lead to problems if you have missing data in columns.**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PerformLogOperation()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim namedRange As Range
    Dim namesArr()

    Set namedRange = wsTarget.Range("HDaERReturns")

    namesArr = GetNamedRangeNames(namedRange)

    CreateNamedRanges namedRange, namesArr

    ''TODO Your log operation code goes here

End Sub

Public Sub CreateNamedRanges(ByVal namedRange As Range, ByVal namesArr As Variant, Optional wbTarget As Workbook)

    Dim currentNamedRange As Long
    Dim tempRange As Range
    Dim tempRangeName As String

    If wbTarget Is Nothing Then Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = namedRange.Parent.Name
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim columnForCount

    startRow = namedRange.Row + 2
    endRow = namedRange.Parent.Cells.Rows.Count
    columnForCount = namedRange.Column

    For currentNamedRange = LBound(namesArr, 2) To UBound(namesArr, 2)

        With namedRange

           Set tempRange = .Columns(currentNamedRange + 1).Offset(2, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1)

        End With

        tempRangeName = Trim$(namesArr(1, currentNamedRange))

        wbTarget.Names.Add Name:=tempRangeName, _
        RefersTo:="=OFFSET(" & sheetName & "!R" & startRow & "C" & columnForCount + currentNamedRange & _
                  ",0,0,COUNTA(" & sheetName & "!R" & startRow & "C" & columnForCount & ":R" & endRow & "C" & _
                  columnForCount & "),1)"

        Set tempRange = Nothing
        tempRangeName = vbNullString

    Next currentNamedRange

End Sub

Public Function GetNamedRangeNames(ByVal namedRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim namesArr()

    With namedRange.Rows(1)

        namesArr = .Offset(, 1).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Value2

    End With

    GetNamedRangeNames = namesArr

End Function
```

**Version 2 for fixed length**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateNamedRanges2(ByVal namedRange As Range, ByVal namesArr As Variant, Optional wbTarget As Workbook)

    Dim currentNamedRange As Long
    Dim tempRange As Range
    Dim tempRangeName As String

    If wbTarget Is Nothing Then Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook

    For currentNamedRange = LBound(namesArr, 2) To UBound(namesArr, 2)

        With namedRange

           Set tempRange = .Columns(currentNamedRange + 1).Offset(2, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1)

        End With

        tempRangeName = Trim$(namesArr(1, currentNamedRange))

        wbTarget.Names.Add Name:=tempRangeName, RefersTo:=tempRange

        Set tempRange = Nothing
        tempRangeName = vbNullString

    Next currentNamedRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to see you again. Thank you for the effort. Unfortunately, I will not be able to test if Version 1 works for me until tomorrow. If it does, of course, I will mark it as an answer, but not before tomorrow. However, I will give you a "thumbs up" for the time you spent on giving not one, but two suggestions, although I was asking just for pointers. Thank you once again!

Comment: Pleased to help. It seemed interesting and not something I had tried before.

Comment: Also, I do not have missing data in cells.

Comment: Can we move to chat, whenever you can?

Comment: I cannot move things to chat but if you are able to enter one of the chat rooms I can meet there or I believe it is possible for me to create a chat room though there is a certain rep count required for you to enter it (weirdly)

Comment: Yes, there is a limitation for me, because one of my questions was closed and I lost some respect points. And, yes, I meant meet in chat, but I forgot about this small detail...

Comment: Your VBA skills are way beyond my own and I find it a bit confusing to get the logic of your answer. Have been trying to get a hold of it for the past two days. What confuses me most is the declaration and set of variables and objects.

Comment: So far I get an error `'1004': Application defined or Object defined error` on this line: `wbTarget.Names.Add Name:=tempRangeName, _
        RefersTo:="=OFFSET(" & sheetName & "!R" & startRow & "C" & columnForCount + currentNamedRange & _
                  ",0,0,COUNTA(" & sheetName & "!R" & startRow & "C" & columnForCount & ":R" & endRow & "C" & _
                  columnForCount & "),1)"` I tried your suggestion for changing `COUNTA` to `COUNT`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Not quite sure.

Comment: I just checked and I still should be able to chat. However, I am not...

Comment: Not that sensitive information. What do you want me to upload? Just the ranges, without names, or named ranges?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167099/discussion-between-qharr-and-i--newb).

Comment: chat room now ?